# Executing a program with arugment from the Run window

Tags: c, windows, command-line

I wrote a simple program in C to create a file (filename comes from the first argument) in the current directory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   FILE *fp;
   if(argc != 2) exit(1);
   fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
   if(fp == NULL) exit(1);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

I compile this with the Visual Studio C compiler, producing the executable `createfile.exe`, which I place on my Desktop and make hidden. I then added my Desktop to my Path environment variable.

My aim is to be able to open the Run window (using Win+R) and type `createfile myfile.tex` to create the file `myfile.tex` on my Desktop. When I execute the program in Command Prompt, the program works as intended, but if I type the command into the Run window, no file is created.

How can I modify the program *or* the environment to make this work as described above?

Comment: perhaps the program doesn't start in the Desktop directory. try to pragmatically set it's path to desktop before creating the file.

Comment: As a general debugging tip, if the file open fails tell the user that it failed and why.  At least an errno.  Because right now you can't tell if the file is being created somewhere unexpected or if it fails to be created at all!

Comment: @IonutHulub You are correct. It was actually creating the file in the directory up one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is probably written, but you do not control the working directory. You can use [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365530%28VS.85%29.aspx), but under Windows, the desktop can be anywhere, and it is localized. It is named "Bureau" in my French Windows XP. That's when [SHGetSpecialFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) comes in.

Most people give up and instead of a program, they create this batch file :

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0
IF NOT EXIST "%1" (
rem this next line is like the unix utility "touch"
echo. 2> %1
)
popd
```

It will create an empty file in the same directory as the batch file it self.

Comment: Thank you @ixe013, that works as intended. Could you possibly explain the line `echo. 2> %1`? I gather that `%1` is the first argument... is `2` stdout or something? Does that `.` mean current directory?

Comment: Echo.  (no spaces) is a command that never fails. You redirect stderr to a file. The command interpreter must create the file,  but nothing will be written to it, thus creating an empty file.